# Sorting Posts by ID from belongs to many relation

Tags: php, laravel, loops, foreach

I have

```
@foreach ($Path->pathtags as $Tag)
    Tag :  {{ $Tag->name }}
        @foreach ($Tag->Posts as $Post )
            Post id   :  {{ $Post->id }}
            Post Name :  {{ $Post->mame}}
        @endforeach
@endforeach
```

So My Output is like

**Tag** : Art

**Post id**   : 8
**Post NAme** : Post About art..

---

**Tag** : fun

**Post id**   : 9
**Post Nnme** : Post About fun..

---

**Tag** : Food

**Post id**   : 11
**Post NAme** : Post About food..

Soi need to get them correctly by id

11

9

8

Answer (score 0):

Add **orderBy** to your relation code

```
$this->belongsToMany('App\Model')->orderByDesc('id');
```

Comment: Add `desc` to it.